# Simple vector equation

Tags: vector-spaces

$\mathbf{r}+(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{a})\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{c}$

Solve for $\mathbf{r}$

The hint I have been given is to consider that $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}=-1$. In that case, I found that $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c}=0$ but I have gotten no further than that. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @SalamanderSylph:  So, what do you want to do?  Are you trying to solve some variable?

Comment: Apologies, solve for $\mathbf{r}$

Comment: how is it that a*b=-1?

Comment: What is b? a scalar?

Comment: b is another vector.

It was a hint that if you take the case a*b=-1 then from that you should be able to find a general solution.

Comment: @SalamanderSylph Is $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{a}$, i.e. is it the standard inner product on $\mathbf{R}^k$?

Comment: You should invest a little more time and effort in writing correctly and clearly your questions: what are a,b,c? In What inner product vector (linear) space you're working?

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with your notation - when used without any context, I've only seen it used for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the dot product.  I think one should use $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ for arbitrary inner products and reserve $\cdot$ for the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  But that's just my opinion, and in this question, I don't think it matters what inner product space you're in.

Here are some hints:

Take your original equation and rearranged it to "solve it for $\mathbf{r}$" as must as you can (the formula for $\mathbf{r}$ will have $\mathbf{r}$ in it).

Plug your expression for $\mathbf{r}$ into your original equation in place of $\mathbf{r}$ and simplify.  You will find that that $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ are linearly dependent (one of them is a constant times the other one.  This includes the case when one or both is the zero vector).

Looking at the original equation, notice that $\mathbf{r}$ is a linear combination of $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$.  Since  $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ are linearly dependent, $\mathbf{r}$ is a constant multiple of $\mathbf{b}$ or a constant multiple of $\mathbf{c}$.

So $\mathbf{r}$ has the form $\lambda\mathbf{b}$ or $\lambda\mathbf{c}$ for some scalar.  replace $\mathbf{r}$ with $\lambda\mathbf{b}$ or with $\lambda\mathbf{c}$ in the original equation to figure out what $\lambda$ is.  Once you have, you're done.

You may have to do several cases, depending on whether $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$, or neither is $\mathbf{0}$.  I haven't done the whole problem, so I don't know exactly what will happen.